# How to get data in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

In this exercice, i'm trying to create a fonction askWeather that would create an AJAX request, then get the web service response and display it on the element with the Id= "askWeather". then, display the result when i click on the button (quelle est la météo sur Paris?)

here's the html part

```
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div><button id="ask-weather">Quelle est la météo sur Paris ?</button></div>
        <div id="weather-result"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

And here's the Javascript Code, it keeps giving me the error "askWeather is not a function"

```
const eltAskWeather = document.getElementById("ask-weather");
const weatherResult = document.getElementById("weather-result");

var askWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();
askWeather.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          weatherResult.innerHTML = response.current_condition.condition;
          console.log(weatherResult.innerHTML);
     }
}

 askWeather.open("GET", "https://www.previsionmeteo.ch/services/json/paris");
 askWeather.send(); 

 eltAskWeather.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     askWeather();         
 });
```

Comment: Your missing a `-` in the url.. its `https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris` also why on earth are you not using fetch api?

Comment: `askWeather` is not a function, so it can't be called like one (`askWeather()`). Just move `askWeather.send()` into the event handler function.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hhaha That's right, there's a missing - but that doesn't solve the problem entirely cuz askWeather it's not a function so i should move askWeather.send() into the event handler or move it all into the event handler. and I'm not using fetch Api because i don't even know what that means hahaha i google it and it said it's related to react, i'm still a beginner hahah :D. Anyway Thank you for replying it helped

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, Thank you that solved the problem but there's a missing - in the url too haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to put the askWeather call within the click handler.

```
const eltAskWeather = document.getElementById("ask-weather");
const weatherResult = document.getElementById("weather-result");

eltAskWeather.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var askWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();
  askWeather.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      weatherResult.innerHTML = response.current_condition.condition;
      console.log(weatherResult.innerHTML);
    }
  }

  askWeather.open("GET", "https://www.previsionmeteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  askWeather.send();

});
```

For more info about some features used:

- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`XMLHttpRequest();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Yes thank you, problem solved, but there's a missing - in the url too haha